# What does "He speaks with a driving if shambolic wit" mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

In New York Times articles [The Great A.I. Awakening](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/14/magazine/the-great-ai-awakening.html), Part I, Section II, *The Unlikely Intern*:

> He (Geoffrey Hinton) has tousled yellowed-pewter hair combed forward in a mature Noel Gallagher style and wore a baggy striped dress shirt that persisted in coming untucked, and oval eyeglasses that slid down to the tip of a prominent nose. **He speaks with a driving if shambolic wit**, and says things like, “Computers will understand sarcasm before Americans do.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**driving** simply means powerful. **shambolic** means chaotic or disorganized. And **wit** means cleverness or the ability to come up with cleaver or witty remarks. I think it really was **if shambolic** that threw you off rather than the words that I just listed which you can easily look up in any online dictionary. I don't know how exactly they describe it in grammar books, but what they're actually trying to say is that the wit that he speaks with may be driving (powerful and persuasive), but it does have a quality of being shambolic (disorganized). So, we could rewrite the sentence like this:

> He speaks with a driving, **though shambolic**, wit.

Or to make things even simpler:

> Even though the wit he speaks with is driving, it's shambolic.

PS: I did some googling around and came up with some more useful information that you might find interesting. The only problem is that the dictionary where I found the description of this grammatical phenomenon of **if** is the one that's built in to Google's main search page, therefore there was really no link to share with you. So, I just took a snapshot. Their explanation is perfect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't know 'if' has the meaning as 'though'.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret it to mean that the writer is saying this person is making witty (i.e. smart and funny) statements that are taking over the conversation but is jumping from topic to topic.

The statement could be taken apart as "a driving wit" and "a shambolic wit."

The first piece, "driving," means "directing" or "dominating." It's a term often used in music, where a particular instrument might be "driving" the song: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bass/comments/4qzjqn/what_are_some_songs_where_the_bass_is_really/ So this sounds like a person whose witty statements are taking over the conversation.

The second piece, "shambolic," can mean "disorganized" or "chaotic." So in this case, the writer is finding this person's conversation difficult to follow, or the speaker is jumping across various topics or unrelated thoughts.

So to make the phrase "He speaks with a driving if shambolic wit" very simple, I would say: "He says smart, funny things that dominate the conversation, but he is changes topics in a way that is hard for others to understand."

Comment: Thank you all the same, what I confused about is the structure of 'if shambolic'.

Comment: "If" in this case is like using the words "but", "although it's" or "albeit."

Comment: What is confusing is that the word "if" is usually used like this: "I will buy this car if it is is a good car."

But another way to use "if" is like the words "albeit," "even though," or "despite": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/although

So the other way would be "This car's design is pretty if old." That's not to say it is pretty because it is old. It is saying that it is pretty even though I think it being old is a bad thing.